# Redirect to a specific page with parameter using the htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a url like:
`v1/club/club-name/12` and `v1/club/club-name/13`

I want it to redirect to:
`v1/features.php?id=12`and `v1/features.php?id=13`

Can anyone please tell me how can I do that with `.htaccess`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^v1/club/[^/]+/(\d+)/?$ v1/features.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```